# Angular http get failed using RequestOptions

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two functions, one works the other gives me this 404 error:

> /get[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

The function getNews gives me that error, I used a console.log to see values of both functions, and I get the same: this.newId = "1", so I call both method with an string using the id of the "New" but it only works the onVote method.

Why on getNews case I got an Object on the request, and on onVote I have the id?

This is the component.ts file:

```
export class NewDetailsComponent implements OnInit
{
    params = new URLSearchParams();
    options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });
    oneNew: New;
    newId: string;

constructor(public http: Http, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
{    }

ngOnInit()
{
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params =>
    {
        this.newId = params['id']
    });

    this.getNews(this.newId)
}

getNews(id: string)
{
    this.params.set('id', id)
    this.options.search = this.params

    this.http
        .get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'news/get' + this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response =>
        {
            this.oneNew = <New>response.json()
        })
}

onVote(id: string)
{
    this.params.set('id', id.toString())
    this.options.search = this.params

    this.http
        .get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'news/Vote', this.options)
        .toPromise()
}
```

Comment: When do you do a console.log of the url, do you have the real url?
Z. Bagley has the answer I think. 
When you see such errors, that means that you have an mix-object where you need a string.

Comment: You have `.get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'news/get' + this.options)` and `.get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'news/Vote', this.options)`. There might be something wrong with `+` and `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your get is using `+` not `,` to add options:

```
getNews(id: string)
{
    this.params.set('id', id)
    this.options.search = this.params

    this.http
        .get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'news/get', this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response =>
        {
            this.oneNew = <New>response.json()
        })
}
```

should fix the issue